# limiting aws ec2 users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to create a sub-account or sub-user that is limited in what he can see and/or do in AWS based on tags for example?

I have tried using policies, but for instances this wouldn't work, because you  can't limit it on a resource level.
This makes it that either they can controll and see everything, or nothing at all.

is there anything that I have missed?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_examples.html#iam-policy-example-ec2-tag-permissions - not very sure, this might help.

Answer (score 1):

The question scope just too wide. Please study the IAM Guides and play around with IAM policy generator condition. 
Even playing around with ARN that allow wildcard, you still need to define some explicit prefix/suffix for those wildcard values. For EC2, you need to understand [EC2 resource ARN](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-ec2) and possible need to mix with "Condition" to add restriction.

Here is an example of using policy generator for a policies that only allow run,start and stop instance, and it restrict to EC2 with resource tag serverX. When you attach this policy to the user, they can only do the following task. You may need to add further condition to make sure the user doesn't see instances belongs to others, by enforcing the tag name creation yourself.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1462794515000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/Name": "serverX"
                }
            },
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2::1234567890:instance/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You can play around with [AWS policy Simulator](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html#policies_policy-simulator-how-it-works). Another good reference is  [AWS inline policies and managed policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html)

Comment: whenever I add the condition with the tag, be it the name, or something else, I get "You are not authorized". When I remove the condition, it works.

Comment: @ShadowFlame : this is just an example, and that's why I say the scope is wide.  There is further IAM roles you need to set. In addition, different resources has its own Condition restriction, some condition doesn't work at all even the features is there. You need to refer to particular resource documentation.

Comment: even in the amazon doc they test on tag values, but it doesn't work either way.

Comment: I still reading this, which point out you will get "You are not authorized" often due to particular situation.
https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx2KPWZJJ4S26H6/Demystifying-EC2-Resource-Level-Permissions

The example will help you "FIX" the error you encounter.